# C#/WMI: How to remotely check if Windows has updates ready to be installed?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, updates

I tried finding a solution for this on google without much luck, perhaps someone here knows how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like this question should go to either superuser.com or serverfault.com (probably the latter).

Comment: I don't believe those sites are ment for developer related questions afaik, so I believe I'm in the right place :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you can do it remotely as such, but you could "fake" it.

Look at the MSDN documentation for the [Windows Update Agent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099%28VS.85%29.aspx), specifically the article called [Searching, Downloading, and Installing Updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102%28VS.85%29.aspx). That contains a script that among other things lists the updates ready to be installed. If you take that bit of the script and amend it to instead write a list to a file, then you could copy the script over to a remote computer, execute the script remotely, then read the file (and finally delete the file and the script from the remote computer to clean up).

You can execute a script remotely using WMI, see this CodeProject article for details for doing so from C#: [Create a Remote Process using WMI in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_Process_using_WMI_.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much, I think that article provides what I need :-)